# How I would move one of multiple mouse pointers programmatically on Linux desktop?

Tags: linux, pointers, mouse, x11, xorg

I have a setup with multiple monitors and multiple mouses (created using

```
xinput create-master
xinput reattach
```

method)
each with independent pointer but within one X session.

Setup can't be changed to multiple independent X sessions.

I already aware of `xdotool` command line tool, and `XWarpPointer` function from XLib but I don't know how to provide they with information which of multiple mouse pointers should be moved.

Comment: 10 minutes ago I didn't know that multiple cursors are possible at all, but the manual page of `xinput` says that `create-master` only works on X servers supporting the "XI2" extension. So I searched for functions provided by that extension and found `XIWarpPointer()`: This seems to be the same as `XWrapPointer()` with the exception that you can specify a "device ID" as additional parameter. This parameter seems to specify which cursor is moved. Unfortunately, this is not reliable information but only a guess...

Comment: Thank you!
`XIWarpPointer` looks exactly like what I need.